# Path of Pagination Library in Joomla 3.*

Tags: component, pagination

I cant find the path of "Pagination" library in joomla 3.3 even though i'm following this [docs](https://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Using_JPagination_in_your_component) it looks like they changed the path in 3.3. I want to extend the pagination for my custom component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc which you are referring is of Joomla 1.5 version.

In Joomla 3.3, you will find the pagination code at `libraries/cms/pagination/pagination.php`